# Running Octave in macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, octave

I installed Octave (6.4.0) using Homebrew.
When I type "`octave`" in the Terminal, it shows in the title of Terminal window that it is "`octave-gui`" but no GUI shows up.
[image]
It also opens an "octave-gui" app in dock, but when I clicked on it, nothing happens. Is it a bug or something else?
[image]

When I tried "`octave-cli`" and "`octave-gui`" separately, it works normally. May I ask if there is a way when I type "`octave`" in the terminal, it opens `octave-cli` as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an alias for `octave`, such that typing `octave` actually runs `octave-cli`. On macOS, this is done by editing the bashrc or bashprofile to include the line `alias octave="octave-cli"`.